# VS Code - Copy Unformatted

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, copy, copy-paste

In Visual Studio Code, how do I copy and paste some text without the colors? I am copying from a markdown file and it seems to copy the theme color when I paste it into an email.

Answer (score 2):

VS Code calls this Syntax Highlighting, even in the case of text and markdown files.

Add this line to settings:

```json
"editor.copyWithSyntaxHighlighting": false
```